# Outputing an array elements as variables inside a function's parameter

Tags: php, arrays, function

Let's say i have the following array, how do i outputting it as variables?

`$required = array('fname', 'email','lname');`

For example like so: `$fname,$email,$lname`

I want to output that array as a function parameter (with the exact order)

like so:
 `$mymail=smtpmailer($to, [required array here]);`

So somehow  i only want to edit the array, which elemets will dynamically be parsed to the function's parameters as variables

Comment: you don't, you use the array index `$mymail = smtpmailer($required[0], $required[1], $required[2])`

Comment: See [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). But if you think you need to do this, you're almost always better off using an associative array.

Comment: use `extract()` functions

Comment: @ChadK, that's perfectly possible. Why can't he?

Comment: @Rafael My understanding of the question is that he wanted to create variables from an array dynamically without first defining the variable. I know about variable variables, but those are ridiculous and quite frankly, bad designs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to pass *values stored in variables whose names are identified by elements in `$required`*, it would be something like this (using recent enough PHP version).

```
$fname = "John"; 
$email = "john@example.com";
$lname = "Doe";

$mymail = smtpmailer($to, ...array_values(compact(...$required)));
```

If you, however, want to pass *values* from `$required` into the `smtpmailer()` function, then you want

```
$required = ["John", "john@example.com", "Doe"]; 
$mymail = smtpmailer($to, ...$required);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create dynamic variables.

Let's suppose that you're using an associative array:

```
$required = array(
    "fname" => "First name",
    "lname" => "Last name",
    "email" => "someone@example.com"
);
```

Here's how to create `$fname` , `$lname` , `$email` variables:

```
foreach ($required as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
}
```

Now you can refer to the variables with their names , for example:

```
echo $email; //Output someone@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array doesn't have keys and is always in the same order you can use the language construct [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

For example:

```
$required = array('John', 'joh.doe@example.com','Doe');
list($fname, $email, $lname) = $required;
$mymail = smtpmailer($to, $fname,$email,$lname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want those text elements 'to','fname','lname' and 'email' are to become  keys of an associative array alongside a value as in the below example you can use the 'extract' function as follows

```
$required = array('to'=>'bobmartin@gmail.com','fname'=>'Bob', 'email'=>'grags@gmail.com','lname'=>'Martin');
extract($required);
$mymail=smtpmailer($to, $fname,$email,$lname);
```

Otherwise, if you have already defined the values somewhere on top for the variables $to, $fname, $email and $lname and you want to dynamically make those strings become variables and need passing to the function, you should use the eval function to convert each string dynamically to a variable and use call_user_func_array to dynamically pass those values as below

```
$required = array('to','fname', 'email','lname');
$inputar = array();
foreach($required as $el)
       array_push($inputar,eval('return $'. $el . ';'));
call_user_func_array("smtpmailer", $inputar);
```